# invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference on QueryRow

Tags: go

I'm new to go and trying to create a signin function, When trying to query row from the database I get this error: `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dere
ference`

The crash caused by this line:

```
    result := db.QueryRow("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=$1", credentials.Email)
```

This is the code:

```
    type Credentials struct {
    Email    string `json:"email", db:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password", db:"password"`
}

func SignIn(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    credentials := &Credentials{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(credentials)
    if err != nil {
        // If there is something wrong with the request body, return a 400 status
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+"dbname=%s sslmode=disable", dbInfo.Host, dbInfo.Port, dbInfo.User, dbInfo.DBname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)

    println(credentials.Email)
    result := db.QueryRow("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=$1", credentials.Email)
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        //If there is an issue with the database, return a 500 error.
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    //We create another instance of 'Credentials' t store the credentials we get from the database
    storedCreds := &Credentials{}

    // Store the obtained password in `storedCreds`
    err = result.Scan(&storedCreds.Password)
    if err != nil {
        // If an entry with the email does not exist, send an "Unauthorized"(401) status
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }

        //If the error is of any other type, send a 500 status
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if credentials.Password != storedCreds.Password {
        //The two passwords does not match, return a 401 status
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    }
}
```

I checked and credentials.Email is not null and I can't understand what causes this error.

Comment: Note that struct tags in Go, by convention, are separated by spaces, not commas. That means that this `\`json:"email", db:"email"\`` goes against convention.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you! I didn't know that.

Comment: Not just "goes against convention", it actually won't work: https://play.golang.org/p/1gg59U9W4dk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```golang
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    // ...
    result := db.QueryRow(...)
```

`db` is probably `nil` because the [`sql.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) failed.

You're not checking `err != nil` like you should always do when a function returns an `error` type.